# What happen if I don't upgrade to blaze plan and wait for 2021 , 1st jan to get another 10GB

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

[image]
Can my project get disable like they said , Question detail are in photo ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as the message says your database may be disabled. It will then be re-enabled when the next billing cycle starts.

For questions like this, I always recommend checking out the [pricing/billing FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#realtime-database). For your question, this fragment seems the most relevant:

> If you're over your download limit, you can upgrade your Firebase plan or **wait until your download limit resets at the start of your next billing cycle**.